# Why is this question closed for being about science, when it has nothing to do with science?

Tags: support

It's here:

[I made a diagram showing the family tree of sapient life in Hinduism. Does anyone know who the Parvata are descended from to unify the family tree?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42918/i-made-a-diagram-showing-the-family-tree-of-sapient-life-in-hinduism-does-anyon)

"I made a diagram showing the family tree of sapient life in Hinduism. Does anyone know who the Parvata are descended from to unify the family tree?"

It's just a simple question about genealogy.

P.S. Was asked to put this as its own question.

Comment: It is now reopened by community members :)

Comment: The link doesnot seem to be functioning c.12/2020 , Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, Yes the closure category was incorrect. Now the question is reopened.

In cases like this when you feel the community members mistakenly closed the question in wrong category, Here are the things you can try:

1. you can flag your own question and explain why it should not be closed, so that one of the moderator can look it up.
2. You can comment under your question mentioning why it should not be closed. If someone casted reopen vote after seeing your comment, it'll go in review queues; there privileged users can see and do the needful.

<sub>**Note: TBH I didn't understand your question clearly, I might have closed it as "Need more focus". Consider composing a question in such a way that even a layman would understand it.**</sub>